# Interactive (but small) shell for Java

Tags: java, shell, scripting, command-line

I'm looking for an interactive shell that I can bolt into a Java application for use in debugging and scripting. I'm not terribly interested in scripting *in Java*, so some more shell-like syntax would be fine, but I would like to be able to load and run 'external commands' on the fly (which would be Java .class files).

Unfortunately my platform is very limited in space --- double digits megabytes of heap space. As such languages like Groovy, Jython and JRuby are unsuitable.

I have found BeanShell, which looks okay, but it appears to have been dead for years and the syntax is rather cumbersome for command line use --- e.g. it would be nice to have stuff like 'help' typed in produce an error message, rather than silence.

Are there any other systems I should look at?

**Edit:** ...aaaaand I've just discovered that BeanShell2 requires reflection abilities that my platform doesn't have, and not even RetroWeaver can help me with this. I shall try BeanShell 1, but I'm not confident.

Comment: It's a Java 1.4 platform and all I can say about it more is that I can't talk about it right now.

Comment: How about Rhino, a Java-based implementation of JavaScript? http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/archive/jnbMar2001.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989017/scripting-in-java-javascript-from-a-server-side-class-file-in-java-1-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/).

> Rhino is an open-source implementation of JavaScript written entirely 
>       in Java. It is typically embedded into Java applications to provide 
>       scripting to end users. It is embedded in J2SE 6 as the default Java 
>       scripting engine.

Comment: Javascript's still not really terribly good in a command line environment --- the syntax is too programming-language-y rather than command prompt-y; but it sounds a bit more plausible than BeanShell, so I shall check it out. Ta.

Comment: **rhino** have TAB completion on classes and methods!!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, [jrunscript](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jrunscript.html)  is something very similar to this and it comes with Java 7. It's experimental and not well supported though.

Answer (score 3):

beanShell is just fine. It is done, not dead. And there seems to be a beanshell 2.0 branch.

Comment: It lack TAB-completion and ANSII colors (( I use **groovysh** to get these features...

Answer (score 1):

[Cliche](https://code.google.com/p/cliche/) can expose user-specified methods that can be called during runtime.